CORS error while working with React and Springboot hosted on localhost
I am trying to do an API call through a react app. The api is hosted on localhost and is build using spring boot. The react app is also hosted on localhost. This is the error I am getting :
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/createUser' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
Below is the react method from where API call is being done:
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const validationErrors = validate();
        if (Object.keys(validationErrors).length > 0) {
            setErrors(validationErrors);
        } else {
            try {
                const response = await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_TASK_MANAGEMENT_APP_API_URL}/createUser`, {
                    crossDomain:true,
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
                    mode: 'cors',
                });
                const data = await response.json();
                if (response.ok) {
                    console.log('Registration successful:', data);
                } else {
                    setErrors({ api: data.message || 'Registration failed' });
                }
            } catch (error) {
                setErrors({ api: 'An error occurred. Please try again.' });
            }
        }
    };

Below is part of package.json:
"name": "task-management-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3000/",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.27.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-tooltip": "^5.28.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },

I am using springboot version 2.7.18 to create the API. Other important dependencies are spring-security, spring-ldap-core and spring-security-ldap. Based on some research that I did for this issue, I have updated my WebSecurityConfig and also added WebConfig(maybe this is not needed). Below are these two classes:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.ldapAuthentication()
        .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=users")
        .contextSource(contextSource())
        .passwordCompare()
        .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
  }

  @Bean
  public DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource() {
    return new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource("ldap://localhost:8389/dc=example,dc=com");
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors()
        .configurationSource(request -> new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues())
        .and()
        .csrf()
        .disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/actuator/**")
        .permitAll() // Adjust permissions as needed
        .antMatchers("/v1/createUser/**")
        .permitAll() // Exclude /v1/user endpoint from authentication
        .antMatchers("/v1/login/**")
        .permitAll() // Exclude /v1/create endpoint from authentication
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin();
  }
}

@Configuration
public class WebConfig {

  @Bean
  public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
      @Override
      public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry
            .addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000") // Change this to your frontend URL
            .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
            .allowedHeaders("*")
            .allowCredentials(true);
      }
    };
  }
}

I have also tried adding @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000") to the controller classes, but still had the same issue.
I have made many changes based on the solutions I found , but none seems to be working.
Thanks in Adavance!

Just for testing, why don't you try adding @CrossOrigin(origins="*") once?

I did that. but still getting the same error.
